# Tableau - Error with Grand Totals ,it's obtained zeros

Tags: tableau-api

1. I actually trying use "Grand Total" in a table , but I obtained zeros in totals, I trying using calculated fields, but I don't know if it's wrong the tableau property or the data.

   [image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Victoria, can you clarify in your example what [a], [b], and [product] consist of? Are all three of them calculated fields? Can you share the formula for each? I tried to reproduce your issue with just [product] as a calculated field, and I was able to get grand totals to populate just fine. Thanks for the clarification.